# how to mock a Concrete class with constructor having another class as parameter, using Moq in c#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I have code which is testing a shopping cart. I am trying to Mock a class (yes not interface, further on this below) which takes another class in the constructor argument.

Constructor of the Test Class is:

```
    public class CheckoutServiceShould
        {
            List<Product> _allMockedProducts; 
            Mock<InMemoryProductService> _mockInMemoryProductService;
            Mock<DiscountService> _discountService;
            Mock<ShoppingBasket> _mockShoppingBasket;


     public List<Product> GetAllProducts()
         {
             return new List<Product>
                {
                new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Apple", Code = "A", Price = new 
    Price { Amount = 100 , Currency = "GBP"}},
                new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Banana", Code = "B", Price = new 
    Price { Amount = 150, Currency = "GBP" }},
                new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Grapes", Code = "C", Price = new 
    Price { Amount = 300, Currency = "GBP" }}
            };
        }

        public CheckoutServiceShould()
        {
            _mockShoppingBasket = new Mock<ShoppingBasket>();
            _mockInMemoryProductService = new Mock<InMemoryProductService> 
   (_mockShoppingBasket.Object);
            _discountService = new Mock<DiscountService>();
            _allMockedProducts = GetAllProducts();
        }
```

I get this message when I try to run the test (Test fails with error)
Test Failed: 
Massage:
Message: Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException : Can not instantiate proxy of class: CheckoutSystem.Service.InMemoryProductService.
Could not find a constructor that would match given arguments:
Castle.Proxies.ShoppingBasketProxy

Comment: Define the `_mockInMemoryProductService` as _mockInMemoryProductService = new Mock<InMemoryProductService> 
   (MockBehavior.Strict,
                new object[] {_mockShoppingBasket.Object});

Comment: tried this appraoch however still getting the same error when I run the test.

Comment: Can you show the definition of `InMemoryProductService` and specifically the constructor you are trying to call?

Comment: Why can't you create an interface IInMemoryProductService?

Comment: `namespace CheckoutSystem.Service` 
    `{`
        `public interface IProductDataService`
        `{`
            `IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts();`

            `Product GetAProduct(string code);`
       `}`
   `}`

Comment: @Koja I have an interface, I have tried using mock interface object as the constructor argument however i still get the same error .. 
I am not sure why is that.
I have a work around which is to create the argument as the class property and not have a constructor argument however  keen to why Mock will not allow me to do so?

Comment: You don't need constructor arguments when mocking an interface. Am I missing something?

Comment: aah rigth got it.. I just had to initialize the concrete service class and pass it the mock interface object.